# How to assign some shortcuts to add some snippets in eclipse IDE?

Tags: eclipse

I'm using eclipse for java i need to add a shortcut key lets say `ctrl+p` (or any other shortcut) to add a line of code say

`System.out.println();`

how do i do this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can go to the window in the toolbar, window-> preference->general(open the list menu)-> keys, there,you can see all the keyboard shortcuts and also add or customize shortcuts.
[image]